# Help finding the roots of a complex function $f(z)=e^{\cos(z)}-1$ where $z \in \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I am stuck with this problem. To solve the problem stated above, I think that I must determine when $\cos(z)=i2\pi q$ for $q\in \mathbb{Z}$ since $e^w=1 \iff w=i2\pi q$

Then:

- By Euler's formula, $\cos(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}=i2\pi q\quad$, this leads to the following: $\quad e^{iz}+e^{-iz}-i4\pi q=0$

Finally

- Multiplying by $e^{iz}$ I get the quadratic equation  $\ e^{2iz}+1-i4\pi qe^{iz}=0$

where the solutions are: $e^{iz}=\dfrac{i4\pi q \pm\ \sqrt{-16\pi^2q^2+1}}{2}$

I don't know where to go from here besides reducing the solutions. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: One idea is to take the logarithm and use the [branches](https://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/05/) of the logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

You can express the solutions in terms of the (real) inverse hyperbolic sine since
\begin{align*}
\cos z = 2\pi iq &\Leftrightarrow  - i\sinh \left( {i\left( {z + \left( {2p + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\pi} \right)} \right) = 2\pi iq \\ & \Leftrightarrow i\left(z+\left( {2p + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\pi\right)=  - \sinh ^{ - 1} (2\pi q) \\ & \Leftrightarrow z =  - \left( {2p + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right)\pi + i\sinh ^{ - 1} (2\pi q).
\end{align*}
Here $p,q\in \mathbb{Z}$ are arbitrary.